# Oracle: Number of partitions 2^n

Tags: oracle, hash, partitioning

Can someone explain me why the number of partitions should be 2,4,8,16.. when using hash partitioning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the following will help you:

http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2009/09/21/hash-partitions-2/

Comment: ok, 2^n prevents that the partitons doesn't have similiar sizes